# Symfony3, Missing argument 1 for Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository::__construct(), how and why

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

I'm making my first small app in symfony, a simple blog.

Now I have been using the documentation for both symfony and doctrine and want to preform a simple, beginner task: **display a json encoded simple table**

Yet somehow I cant seem to get along with doctrine.

Here is my data (apart form the view which does nothing but display the value):

```
//AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use AppBundle\Entity\Post;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $database = new Post();
        $output = $database->findAll();

        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [
            'base_dir' => realpath($this->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/..').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
            'x' => json_encode($output)
        ]);
    }
}


<?php
//AppBundle/Entity/Post.php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="sqltest")
*/
class Post extends EntityRepository
{
    //The post for now uses data from a temponary test table
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
    */
    private $name;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer", scale=2)
    */
    private $number;



    /**
     * Get id
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     * @param string $name
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set number
     * @param integer $number
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setNumber($number)
    {
        $this->number = $number;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get number
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getNumber()
    {
        return $this->number;
    }

}
```

Problem is when I try to display the website i get this exception

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for
>   Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository::__construct(), called in
>   C:\Users\Alan\Desktop\symf-blog\src\AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php
>   on line 19 and defined

Problematic line being the one with `$database = new Post();`

I am very new in this and am aware that the response is very simple and I just don't see it. When answering please provide and explanation which [even a dead rabbit](https://www.artgallery.nsw.gov.au/media/collection_images/4/434.1997.9%23%23S.jpg) could understand.

Pretty thanks for your patience.

PS: Also an explanation about what the `$em` variable I've seen so much about is for and from where do I get it would be nice

Comment: Are you familiar with OOP? If so [check](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.5/class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityRepository.html) here for the parameters required by `EntityRepository` the class you're inherit from. So you will need to pass them or don't extend at all (check [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html))

Comment: I understand the $class element, but still couldn't find any info on the origin of variable $em

Comment: This can give you a tip `$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); $entities = $em->getRepository("CommonBundle:Bank")->findAll();`

Comment: Reset a bit and read the getting started chapter:  http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html Doctrine is an ORM not an Active Record module so having an entity extend a repository makes zero sense.  No need to fret.  If you really want an Active Record approach, there are several to pick from.

Comment: @ReynierPM `$this` refers to what in that case?

Comment: @ReynierPM You'r code works but returns an empty array `[{},{}]`.
I used it with `getRepository("AppBundle:Post")`

Comment: Can you update your code with the newest changes? Also you're using Symfony 2.??? which version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're want a repository class for custom DB functions then this is the right way to do it:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;    
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class PostRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findAll()
    {
        return $this->findBy(array(), array('id' => 'DESC', 'createdAt' => 'DESC'));
    }  
   ....
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); 
$entities = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Post")->findAll();
```

Remove the annotations (them belongs to the entity). Also pay attention to what @james_bond told you. Try that!

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/repository.html), you access custom repository classes through doctrine entity manager.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();  
$posts = $em->getRepository('YourBundle:Post')->findAll();
```

Also you're mixing your entity definition with your repository definition, which is not a good idea.

Please refer to the [doctrine documentation in symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html) for proper usage.

Comment: Added `    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entities = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Post")->findAll();`
And later printed inside `$json_encode`. 
The result was `[{}{}{}]` (for a 3 row table, adding, made more `{}` inside)